# R regular expression: find the last but one match

Tags: regex, r

I need a regular expression script (in R language) which finds the last but one match.

Here is an example:

```
input = c("(test1(test2(test3","(((((othertest1(othertest2(othertest3")
regexpr('the_right_regular_expression_here_which_can_finds_the_last_but_one_'(' ', input)
```

The result has to be: **7** and **16**, because in the first case the last but one '(' is in a 7th position (from left), and in the second case the last but one '(' in in the 16th position (from left).

I've found a regular expression which can find the last match, but I could not transform it in the right way:

```
\\([^\\(]*$
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Depending on what you mean by *find*, this might do it for you: `\([^(]*\([^(]*$`. [See it here](https://regex101.com/r/cY6nG7/1).

Comment: Try `"(\\([^(]*){2}$"`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To match a chunk of text beginning with the last but one `(`, you may use

```
"(\\([^(]*){2}$"
```

*Details*:

- `(\\([^(]*){2}` - 2 sequences of:

  - `\(` -  a literal `(`
  - `[^(]*` - zero or more chars other than `(`
- `$` - end of string.

R test:

```
> input = c("(test1(test2(test3","(((((othertest1(othertest2(othertest3")
> regexpr("(\\([^(]*){2}$", input)
[1]  7 16
attr(,"match.length")
[1] 12 22
attr(,"useBytes")
[1] TRUE
```